# Check if a column exists in Hive through shell script

Tags: shell, hive

I am trying to write a shell script file that would check inside the file to see if there is a column present inside the file, but not inside the table's schema then add that column into the table's schema. While if a column is not present in the file but is there in the table's schema then remove that column. Column names are included in the file as headers.

I tried to find the answer to my above question here on SO, but I could not find the answer to it. If it is present here then declare it a duplicate question. Thanks for all the help.

The file might contain something like this:

```
First  Last   ID
James  Hardy  1
John   Smith  2
```

And the table may have:

```
Last       ID
Hartley    4
Birkhold   5
```

So then I need to write a script that would add a new column called `First` into the table's schema, but if some column was present in the table but not in the file then it needs to be deleted. If a column already there in both file and table, then do nothing, but just add the data into the table

Comment: Can you provide an example? Does the file follow a specific format?

Comment: @ady6831983 I have updated the question with an example. Please check now.

Comment: What is that you tried so far to get it working? Share your effort!!!